# Switch between cameras

Tags: vb.net, video, camera, webcam-capture

I have a list of items of my webcams in a project. So, I would like to preview webcam's Video when I click it's name in the Cameras list items.

I can preview default webcam through `avicap32` library but my problem is I can't post the name of my camera Or `deviceID` of camera to `avicap32` to preview this camera.

Please advise me to solve this problem.

It's the new issue:

When I run the application the first time open the "Video source" window and I want to select the video source of my cameras and I should select one camera to use, but I like to choose the camera in my application, not in the "windows video source window".

Comment: Eventually you will have to consider a more suitable API: DirectShow via [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Hello Romeo, Do you have experience of directshwo.net? I have to switch between webcams and preview. It's not important use whether API. If you have a good solution to do that please advise me